# How to disconnect in Bump api in iphone sdk

Tags: ios4

I am working on a project integrated with Bump feature. 
I have updated my api to 3.0 because older versions have "UniqueIdentifier" in .a file of Bump api.
Now issue is that I am not able to disconnect current session on screen navigation.I called following method to disconnect

```
[[BumpClient sharedClient] disconnect];
```

but above method does not works.Can anyone help me how to disconnect( or End) current session using Bump3.0 api on screen navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you..your code is correct..you try putting NSLog and check in this method,whats going on after disconnect.

```
[[BumpClient sharedClient] setConnectionStateChangedBlock:^(BOOL connected) {
    if (connected) {
        NSLog(@"Bump connected...");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Bump disconnected...");
    }
}];
```

http://bu.mp/company/faq

https://github.com/bumptech/bump-api-ios

https://github.com/bumptech/bump-api-ios/blob/master/libBump/BumpClient.h

Comment: @ Thanx Json, But none of them works, I have tried all thins but could not disconnect on screen navigation.Even I set [[BumpClient sharedClient]setBumpable:NO] in viewWillDissapear & then called disconnect method.